# Openfire installation error

Tags: openfire

Openfire can not start. its showing below error messages.

```
> Openfire 4.1.5 [Oct 16, 2017 4:10:30 PM]
>     Successfully loaded plugin 'admin'.
>     Successfully loaded plugin 'search'.
>     Finished processing all plugins.
>     Error starting 5222: Address already in use: bind
>     Error starting 5223: Address already in use: bind
>     Error starting 5269: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
>     Error starting 5275: Address already in use: bind
>     Error starting 5276: Address already in use: bind
>     Error starting 5263: Address already in use: bind
```

Comment: Its self explainatory, you got something listening already on ports dedicated to openfire.

Answer (score 1):

This instance of Openfire could not properly start up, because most (all?) of the ports it tries to listen on, were already bound by another application.

The set of ports used by Openfire is pretty specific, and on your server, they're all in use. It appears that you're already running an XMPP server. You've likely started Openfire twice, or running another XMPP server.

A common mistake that leads to this is to have Openfire installed as a service, having the service started, and then try to manually start Openfire (again).